# Jena RDF API write method

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I'm using Apache Jena API to read a rdf file and write it out to the console. 
This is the Java code.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("file.rdf");
model.read(in, null);
model.write(System.out);
```

This is the RDF file.

```xml
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'
  xmlns:vcard='http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#'
 >
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A0">
    <vcard:Family>Smith</vcard:Family>
    <vcard:Given>John</vcard:Given>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about='http://somewhere/JohnSmith/'>
    <vcard:FN>John Smith</vcard:FN>
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A0"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about='http://somewhere/SarahJones/'>
    <vcard:FN>Sarah Jones</vcard:FN>
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A1"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about='http://somewhere/MattJones/'>
    <vcard:FN>Matt Jones</vcard:FN>
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A2"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A3">
    <vcard:Family>Smith</vcard:Family>
    <vcard:Given>Rebecca</vcard:Given>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This is the output.

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" > 
</rdf:RDF>
```

The problem is that my program does not write out the whole RDF data. 
How can I write out the whole RDF data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pretty much the same application and it worked. I cannot tell you what is wrong with your code but at least this is how I did it:

```
Model myModel = FileManager.get().loadModel("file.rdf");
```

then I was able to read again with:

```
myModel.write (System.out, "RDF/XML");
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'm very happy for you